# Can't telnet to a Linux port

Tags: linux, centos, port

There is the following listener:

```
telnet -na | grep 8000

tcp   0   0.0.0.0:8000   0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
```

I can do telnet 1.2.3.4 8000 from the 1.2.3.4 server and it connects, but same command from other machines don't connect (say 1.2.3.4 is machine IP).

I did the following:

```
chkconfig iptables off
chkconfig ip6tables off
service iptables stop
service ip6tables stop
vi /etc/selinux/config {set to disable }
```

did a reboot

```
sestatus {resulted in SELinux status: disabled}
lsof -i | grep 8000 {no results}
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

telnet 1.2.3.4 22 does work, but to 8000 does not. no firewall on other machines. Linux is Centos.

What else can be tried?

Comment: Whatever you run on 8000, are you sure you did not config that thing to listen on some of the private IP-s? 127.0.0.1 is typical.

No, forget it. Now I can see, you aimed at 1.2.3.4

Comment: -1 the title makes no sense and the body of your question shows a port you can telnet to that runs linux. So your title is not summarizing well whatever problem you have

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you get when you try to connect to 1.2.3.4 port 8000 from remote machines: is it a "connection refused", a timeout, or a "no route to host"? (The latter 2 indicate network traffic being blocked).

Things to try:

Check "`lsof -i :8000`" instead of the "grep 8000".

Verify that it isn't a problem with your listener application by shutting it down, and using netcat -- e.g "`nc -4 -l 8000`" and trying the connect again.

Verify again that you can ping 1.2.3.4 from the other machines.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tcpdump` to find out whether packets from remote host are reaching your server. Run

`tcpdump -n port 8000`

If you see the output, then packets are reaching your server but being dropped by local firewall or something else.
If you output is blank, then packets are **not** reaching your server. In this case amending server's configuration is useless, because you have connectivity issues between your client and webserver.  To solve this out you may run on client:

`tracert <webserver's IP>` (on Windows)
or
`traceroute <webserver's IP>` (on Unix)

save output to file and call your ISP/network administrator/someone else who cares. They will probably ask for trace - you have it saved in file.